# On page refresh store data is clearing in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hi I am using redux store and it is working fine and storing data, When i refresh page store is becoming empty, How to hold data in store after page refresh.

Comment: save the state to localstorage, then hydrate the state from localstorage next time when page is reloaded. https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

Redux will never keep data across page refreshes by default.

I'd recommend using localstorage on window destroy to store the redux store.

And then when you create the store, you can pull in from localstorage.

This won't work if there's any non-serializable data in the state, though.

There is also a library that does a similar thing: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

It looks like it would be a better option for more complicated or larger stores as localstorage is synchronous and will prevent rendering as it works.

Comment: how about redux-persist,

Comment: I figured there would be a library to do the same, but I haven't had need of one yet, so I didn't know off the top of my head.